# How to get all sockets connected on 2 different nodes through socket.io-redis?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, socket.io-redis

I am connecting sockets to port 8100 and port 8200.
Both of them are using socket.io-redis module to share sticky sessions, How do I get the total number of connections I have on the website?